# fixing the size of a window in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to fix the size of a window in vim? In a way that when I do a `Ctrl-W _`, it would maximize the current window but the one I fixed the size would stay same.

Comment: Do you mean vim or gvim? I.e. are you referring to the OS window or the buffer windows in Vim?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the options you're looking for are:

```
set wfh  
set wfw
```

(set WinFixHeight, set WinFixWidth)
You can set them on the window that you want to stay the same, but unfortunately only `Ctrl-W =` listens to that, not `Ctrl-W _`